# How to compile C file through Terminal

Tags: c, macos, terminal, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a C file that I have saved on my computer and I'm trying to compile the file with Terminal on my Mac OS X El Capitan by typing out `gcc - g -wall -werror -o getit.out -std=c11 getit.c`, but I keep getting this error stating:

```
    Sandra$ gcc -g -wall -werror -o getit.out -std=c11 getit.c
    clang: error: unknown argument: '-wall'
    clang: error: unknown argument: '-werror'
    clang: error: -E or -x required when input is from standard input
    clang: error: no such file or directory: 'g'
```

I have downloaded Xcode and installed it, but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. If anyone could provide insight that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT:**

So as stated by @md xf I tried 
    gcc - g -Wall -Werror -o getit.out -std=c11 getit.c

but I still got an error stating

```
clang: error: -E or -x required when input is from standard input
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'g'
```

**Forgot to list all of my errors in my original post

Comment: Perhaps you should type `gcc -g ...` rather than `gcc - g ...`. Note the space between `-` and `g`

Comment: If you are copying from the website, ensure that there is no "invisible" spaces in the copied text.

Comment: Yes that was part of the problem! Thank you @HKTonyLee

Comment: the `-` before the `g` is telling the compiler that the input is to be switched to stdin,  so anything after the `-` is seen as garbage.  To fix it, remove the space between the `-` and the `g`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the W in `-Wall` and `-Werror` need to be capitalized. A capital flag and a lowercase flag will have two completely different functions. So you would rewrite it as `gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c11 -o getit.out getit.c`.

In response to your edit you could also try:

1. writing `getit.c` as your first option
2. making sure there is no space between `-` and `g` (`-g`)
3. removing the `-std=c11` if it's not absolutely necessary

It seems like you are typing something different than what's shown here. The error messages make it seem like there's a space between `-` and `g`.

Comment: I tried your input, but I still got an error stating `clang: error: -E or -x required when input is from standard input clang: error: no such file or directory: 'g'`

Comment: @SandraBae You could try rearranging it so that your input file is first, e.g. `gcc getit.c ...`

Answer (score 1):

> clang: error: unknown argument: '-wall'
>
> clang: error: unknown argument: '-werror'

The W in -Wall and -Werror need to be capitalized. That explains the above errors showed by `gcc`.

> clang: error: -E or -x required when input is from standard input
>
> clang: error: no such file or directory: 'g'

This error is due to space character between `g` flag option and `hypen(-)`. Remove the space and this error will run away.

The command to compile your program should be like this:
`gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c11 -o getit.out getit.c -g`.

Answer (score -2):

please use command as below to compile the C file

gcc - g -Wall -Werror -o getit.out -std=c11 getit.c

Comment: This is the command to compile and link, i.e. to build an executable actually.